# The use of going to in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

I sometimes see a speaker saying:
I'm going to disagree with you.
I'm going to have to agree with you.

How does "going to" work in the above sentence?

Comment: [Related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/39802/48335)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, 'going to' is more formal.

Saying "I disagree with you" can come across as being harsh.

It's different for this case, but "going to" mainly signifies something in the near future (*I'm going to the market tomorrow. Are you going to come with me?*).